# How make a UITableViewCell text like Facebook messenger for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When we received a message on Facebook Mesenger, the text gets bold in UITableViewCell after touching the cell and view the message and then return to the UITableView, the cell text is no longer in bold.

How to create this behavior?

Below my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
.
.
.
//Implementation
.
.
.

 [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"lido"];

    NSError*error;

    // Escreve no banco a alteração
    [context save:&error];

    for (int index = 0; index<[fetchedObjects count]; index++) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"lido"]);

.
.
.
// Implementation

}




-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
.
.
.

//Implmentation

.
.
.

if ([[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]  valueForKey:@"lido"] == 1) {

        //Torna fonte bold
       cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];

      [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"],[processosLocal valueForKey:@"data_pdf"]]];

        return cell;
    }else{

        // Exibe a fonte normal caso o valor de "lido" seja 0 (zero)        
         [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"], [processosLocal valueForKey:@"data_pdf"]]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Ok i will post the code...

Comment: HI! I post the code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the TYPE of data in `Core Data` to `@"lido"`. For the type in `Core Data` to `@"lido"` field is STRING and I was making a direct comparison with an `INT` in the `IF ()`.

Wrong code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey: @ "read"] == 1) {
. 
. 
. 
// Other implementation
```

Correct Code!

```
if ([[[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey: @ "read"] isEqual: @ "1"]) {
. 
. 
. 
// Other implementation
```

Xcode has no way to know the type of data that comes from `Core Data`, and at runtime no problems because the `STRING` type to the `if ()`, equals the numerical value, then to make the correct verification had to use the method `isEqual:`

Answer (score 0):

- Your model object should store the state of whether your message is read it not. Your `cell` should present text in bold when the message is unread. When the state changes reload the `cell` and let it configure itself according to this state.
- It's a very common pattern. Was there some particular difficulty you were having in trying to implement it?

Comment: Yes i have a storage persistence to sabe state of message, when the cell is selected l, her is mark how READ in data storage, but how i implement the cell?

Comment: if you has a code example this will help! I created a code, i use a 'if()' for detect attribute UNREAD in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:', but this don't did the change.

Comment: Hey, i posted my code! Look and say what i do wrong.